# Web Service Composition using BPEL

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, composition, bpel

Is there any tutorial for web service composition in BPEL designer in Eclipse? I have very little information about BPEL.
thanks for any answer or comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a article[1] some times back and It covers very basics. I used 'WSO2 Developer Studio' in that article and it has embedded 'Eclipse BPEL Designer'. But steps are very similar.

[2][3] are also good blog posts. [3] covers a sample with correlation. Hope this will help you.

[1] - http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2011/04/using-carbon-studio-model-wsbpel-process-using-bpel-editor

[3] - http://thiliniishaka.blogspot.com/2012/10/develop-ws-bpel-process-using-wso2.html

[2] - http://nandikajayawardana.blogspot.com/2013/04/developing-business-process-with.html